# Pivoting Data Using MySql based on month in a date

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, transpose

Data in table tbl_xyz is stored this way

```
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+
customerId  | amount    |   fee | rate  |   installment |   dateIssued  |
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+
1           |   200000  |   3000|   50  |           4   |   2019-01-01  |
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+
2           |   206000  |   3000|   30  |           4   |   2019-01-03  |
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+
3           |   200000  |   3000|   50  |           3   |   2019-01-11  |
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+
4           |   200000  |   3000|   40  |           4   |   2019-01-12  |
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+
5           |   340000  |   3000|   20  |           4   |   2019-01-13  |
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+
6           |   20000   |   3000|   50  |           2   |   2019-01-15  |
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+
7           |   600000  |   3000|   50  |           4   |   2019-01-15  |
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+
8           |   250000  |   6000|   70  |           1   |   2019-01-15  |
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+
```

I want to have this output

Note: this output is for all records dateIssued is of any date in January only.

```
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
customerId  | amount    |   fee | rate  |   installment |   dateIssued  |   total   |   inst/mo |   JAN |   FEB |   MAR |   APR |
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
1           |   200000  |   3000|   50  |           4   |   2019-01-01  |   300000  |     75500 |  75500|  75500|  75500|  75500|
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
2           |   206000  |   3000|   30  |           4   |   2019-01-03  |   267800  |    66950  | 66950 | 66950 | 66950 | 66950 |
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
3           |   200000  |   3000|   50  |           3   |   2019-01-11  |   300000  |    100000 | 100000| 100000| 100000|      0|
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
4           |   200000  |   3000|   40  |           4   |   2019-01-12  |   ...     |      ...  |   ... |   ... |   ... |   ... |
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
5           |   340000  |   3000|   20  |           4   |   2019-01-13  |   ...     |      ...  |   ... |   ... |   ... |   ... |
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
6           |   20000   |   3000|   50  |           2   |   2019-01-15  |   ...     |      ...  |   ... |   ... |   ... |   ... |
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
7           |   600000  |   3000|   50  |           4   |   2019-01-15  |   ...     |      ...  |   ... |   ... |   ... |   ... |
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
8           |   250000  |   6000|   70  |           1   |   2019-01-15  |   425000  |    425000 |425000 |      0|      0|      0|
------------+-----------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Here are some conditions:

total = (amount + (amount * rate)/100)

inst/mo = (amount + (amount * rate)/100) / installment

JAN, FEB, MAR and APR columns depends on month in dateIssued.

In above example all records are of January only. For February it would have been FEB, MAR, APR and MAY. 
And distribution of values in each month depends on installment.

Comment: *JAN, FEB, MAR and APR columns depends on month in dateIssued.* ... so why are there non-NULL data in *FEB*, *MAR*, and *APR* columns for these January dated records?

Comment: @Parfait because the number of installments is 1, so taking total divides by 1 you will have the same value for one month.